# Javascript, toggle radio button images with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have a form where I have replaced the radio buttons with images, and when the images are clicked, they show a darker form of the image to show that it is active, but, I can't quite figure out how to get the darker image to go back to the standard one when I click on a different radio button image. Here is what I've got so far.

```js
$("[name=make]").on({
  "click": function() {
    var val = $(this).attr('value');
    console.log("Value: " + val);
    var imgName = "#" + val + "-icon";
    $(imgName).attr('src', '/images/make-icons/' + val + '-hover.png');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input id="ford" class="dis-none" type="radio" name="make" value="ford">
  <img class="make-icons" src="/images/make-icons/ford.png" id="ford-icon">
</label>
<label>
  <input id="chevrolet" class="dis-none" type="radio" name="make" value="chevrolet">
  <img class="make-icons" src="/images/make-icons/chevrolet.png" id="chevrolet-icon">
</label>
<label>
  <input id="gmc" class="dis-none" type="radio" name="make" value="gmc">
  <img class="make-icons" src="/images/make-icons/gmc.png" id="gmc-icon">
</label>
<label>
  <input id="dodge" class="dis-none" type="radio" name="make" value="dodge">
  <img class="make-icons" src="/images/make-icons/dodge.png" id="dodge-icon">
</label>
<label>
  <input id="toyota" class="dis-none" type="radio" name="make" value="toyota">
  <img class="make-icons" src="/images/make-icons/toyota.png" id="toyota-icon">
</label>
<label>
  <input id="nissan" class="dis-none" type="radio" name="make" value="nissan">
  <img class="make-icons" src="/images/make-icons/nissan.png" id="nissan-icon">
</label>
```

Comment: It would probably help if you updated your demo to use the relevant images (otherwise it's hard to see your problem).

Answer (score 0):

check for the state of the radio

```
$("[name=make]").on({
  "change": function() {
    var suffix = '';
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        suffix = '-hover';
    }
    var val = $(this).attr('value');
    console.log("Value: " + val);
    var imgName = "#" + val + "-icon";
    $(imgName).attr('src', '/images/make-icons/' + val + suffix + '.png');
  }
});
```